# Non-line-of-sight distance approximation between trasmitter and receiver

Tags: rf, infrared, distance

I have one stationary object in a 2d plane (no z-axis). Let's say this stationary sphere is in the middle of a rectangular plane. I have another object in the same rectangular plane that is in motion all the time. The second object moves around the first but the motion is really unpredictable (does not revolve in a circle). The first object needs to track the coordinates of the second object at all times. Given the first object knows the (0,0) of the rectangular plane and its current location, how can it accurately track the second item?

IR sensors probably won't work. All I can think of is using RF transmitter/receiver. By putting two receivers inside Object 1, it may be possible to triangulate any (comparable to voltage) signal sent by the moving object (the transmitter).

Any suggestions on this one (and legal one at that)? Let's assume the rectangular plane is not that big (0.4m x 0.5m).

[image: Example behavior]

Comment: What sort of accuracy to you need? My initial feel is that while RF might be OK for detecting the bearing using a doppler direction type system signal strength won't work well for the range. You might be able to transmit a sequence and work out the phase difference between when it's received at each antenna, but with them all bunched together in object 1 I'd expect the requirements to be very extreme, you'd probably need to resolve the time differences in the picosecond range.

Comment: @PeterJ Basically I want to take 20 points per second (every 50ms) and interpolate in gaps. The distance measurement needs to be quite accurate though, with the error margin being under 1mm.

Comment: There are small-scale laser range finders; these also come as rotating devices which output relative angle and range. 20 revs. per second may be a little much asked, but devices with 2-5 rps. are readily available.

Comment: @PeterJ Also what if I put two receivers at (0,0) and (10, 0) instead of 1 at (5, 5). Is this configuration easier? If this configuration works, what technology would best suit this system?

Comment: You will definitely have better results with two distinct sensors than with one alone.

Comment: @HannoBinder max 0.4m width and 0.5m length.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the specs in your question until after I commented :)

Comment: "Scanning Laser Range Finder" may be the correct term to search for. -- A first shot yielded for example: http://www.robotshop.com/en/rplidar-360-laser-scanner.html, which at US$400 seems to be at the low end of the price range :-\

Comment: @HannoBinder Thanks for the comment. However, I want to avoid systems that require round trip techniques. I just want to track the location of the moving object and save it somewhere. Receivers are not required to send commands back to the moving object. So the optimum system for me would be for the transmitter to transmit something and depending on the difference in characteristics of this signal at the two receivers, I want to estimate the exact position. And yes $400 is expensive :'(

Comment: The laser scanner does not involve any kind of "round trip", except for the ability of the object's surface to reflect some light (IR).

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking that generating an alternating magnetic field will work.

A field can be generated by a round loop centred at 0,0 and the amplitude of the field measured by the moving object. When the moving object is further away, the smaller is the magnetic field detected - this gives you distance but not direction.

So, imagine two half-moon back-to-back coils are used for sending out different frequencies. One half moon is biased to generate signals in one direction and the other half moon produces its field in a different direction maybe like this: -

[image]

The two frequencies will be picked up by the moving object and the ratio of the amplitudes will narrow down the direction angle.

Using three coils and 3 different frequencies should define the direction angle unambiguously. The same principle applies to three phase induction motors except in this case three different frequencies are used.

The "thing that moves" has to have a small receive coil and the ability to transmit it's location to the central unit.

A variation on this is possible - I can envisage the moving object being passive (with just a tuned coil acting like a shorted turn as in simple RFID tags that alert a storekeeper if you are stealing something) - its effect is measurable by all of the three static coils due to eddy current induction in the moving coil. The relative amplitudes of eddy current define the position and, importantly, I think this will work with a common operating frequency.

There will be cross interference between static coils but this is a static "error".

Problems arise with large pieces of metal entering or leaving the "arena" because these can be induced with significant eddy currents but, it is worth pointing out, the eddy currents induced into the moving object will be "tuned" because of the nature of its coil and capacitor and I think this will produce a much more significant signal compared to bits of metal entering or leaving the arena.

If this doesn't work then the moving object's tuned coil can be simply modulated on-off when it gets enough power to do so - just like a passive tag ID system on a door entry point.

Comment: Let me look into this. Great concept. But this assumes that the coil inside the moving object does not change orientation? Which might not be the case. But I need to look into this in more detail.

Comment: It can rotate - I envisage the coil in the moving object to be circular so if it rotates it still gets the same field intensity.

Answer (score -1):

How loud is the object?  Can you use a microphone array?  I'm sure there are pre made array projects on the net.